# rails ransack gem to search json column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have a field as json column and i have to search all the phone values inside that column, i have searched for it and i have not found any document using ransack. Is it possible to use ransaack to search json column?
I have used the ransack to search other fields, so i have to use ransack or something that can combine both result

my json column looks like this

```
{"phone1"=>"", "relationship_type1"=>"", "relationship_name1"=>"", "phone2"=>"", "relationship_type2"=>"", "relationship_name2"=>"", "phone3"=>"", "relationship_type3"=>"", "relationship_name3"=>"", "phone4"=>"", "relationship_type4"=>"", "relationship_name4"=>""}
```

phone1, phone2,3,4 should be searcheable.

Answer (score 7):

See the [Ransack wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#3-search-for-a-key-in-an-hstore-column-in-this-example-searching-an-hstore-column-called-properties-for-records-containing-a-key-called-link_type)

For each JSON column add one of these to your model, and it will enable your JSON column to be ransacked as normal columns:

```rb
ransacker :phone1 do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:json_column], 'phone1')
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a table with a json column called `properties`, you should be able to tell `ransack` to look inside the phone1 with the following snippet:

```
ransacker :phone1 do
  Arel.sql("table.properties ->> 'phone1'")
end
```

Comment: Would you like to improve your code-only answer by adding some explanation?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code for reference. Code-only answers have low utility and are often confusing.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4.2+ (Arel 6.0+) :

- model_name : Employee
- column_name: extra_details (jsonb type)
- json_key   : hobbies

```
# in models/employee.rb
ransacker :hobbies do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->>', parent.table[:extra_details], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('hobbies'))
end
```

Test it console :

```
Employee.search({ "hobbies_cont" => "Reading" }).result
# or
Employee.ransack({ "hobbies_cont" => "Painting" }).result
```

- both **search** & **ransack** work. ***search*** [will be deprecated](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#ransack-search-method) in the next major version of Ransack.
- `->` does not work as intended. `->>` works.

[Ransack Wiki.](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers)

[Blog/tutorial.](https://axiomq.com/blog/using-ransackers-to-search-for-a-key-in-postgresql-json-column/)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct except that Arel 6+ will raise an exception if you send in just a string for the last arg, you have to use `Arel::Nodes::build_quoted('phone1')` instead of `'phone1` in this example

Also, I found that if you are going to use a `ransacker` on the model you have to call it with `Model.search` instead of `Model.ransack` there may be some exception to this but using `Model.search` is what worked for me.

`#search` takes a hash of the ransacker you're going to use added with the predicate you are working with (e.g. `phone1_cont`, or `phone1_eq`)

So to make the above work you'd have to call `Model.search({phone1_cont: "555"})`